# Storing a record with JOOQ shows different behavior on insert in h2 and MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, h2, jooq

When storing a record with jooq it generates different SQL for h2 and MSSQL, which makes it impossible to use quickperfs @ExpectInsert/@ExpectSelect annotations in test, since it counts differently. The generated SQL looks for H2 like:

> select "ID" from final table (insert into...

and for MSSQL:

> declare @result table ([ID] bigint); insert into ...

so in the first case quickperf does not count an insert but an select. So, why is the generated SQL so different? What are my options to solve this?  Any hints are much appreciated.

I used the jooq store() method and insertInto() with no difference in the generated SQL.

Comment: Different (R)DBMS use (very) different dialects of SQL. This is expected behaviour, as it's unlikely that the syntax for one (R)DBMS's dialect will be compatible with another (sometimes even *very* simple queries aren't transferable without a small amount of translation).

Comment: But if you use H2 with prepared statements then no extra select is needed for the automatically generated ID. I can just use a insert with returning generated key and thats it

Answer (score 0):

The expectation of jOOQ (or any ORM) producing the exact same SQL for different SQL dialects is wrong. The whole point of abstracting over SQL is, in parts, to be able to generate SQL that "does the job".

In this case, it seems you're running some sort of statement that tries to implement `RETURNING` behaviour, where generated keys are to be fetched from the RDBMS after insertion. Both H2 and SQL Server have means to do this:

- H2 implements the standard SQL data change delta table (`FINAL TABLE (...)`)
- SQL Server has an `OUTPUT` clause, but it has some limitations, including not being able to produce trigger generated values, so jOOQ generates a statement batch which fetches results into a in-memory temporary table.

You can find more details about this topic in this blog post about [the many ways of returning data from SQL DML statements, on the jOOQ blog](https://blog.jooq.org/the-many-ways-to-return-data-from-sql-dml/), which explains what jOOQ does behind the scenes, and why.

Your question "What are my options to solve this?" is harder to answer, because I'm not convinced your motivation here is reasonable: That of expecting identical SQL for both RDBMS.

Perhaps a much better question is: [Do you really need H2 (as a test database product)? Here's jOOQ's take on this](https://blog.jooq.org/using-h2-as-a-test-database-product/).